# In what contexts can you use greater than as text in html

Tags: html

In what contexts can I use the greater than symbol `<` as text in HTML?
For example `<` & `<=` parse render as text perfectly fine if they are in a tag:

```html
<p>
    <
    <=
</p>
```

However `<t` will be parsed as HTML by the browser and not produce the text `<t`.

Is there a rule for what characters can proceed the greater than symbol for the browser to assume that it is the start of a tag?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you feel you might need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is: almost never.

Only inside quoted attribute values (and in raw text tags like `script` and `style`) are you permitted to write `<` unescaped. I think attribute *names* permit these too, but not `>` (though why you would put a `<` in an attribute name is beyond me).

Browsers will do their best to recover from bad HTML, so sometimes you might get away with it if you forget.

But it's best to always encode your entities.

You should scan the HTML spec, but [here's one relevant chapter](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax) with some of the constraints listed in various sections.

Use [an HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) in strict mode to make sure you're getting it right; the HTML you gave in your question is rejected by the linked tool, with a suggestion to switch to `&lt;`.